# Auto Complete Extender for multiline textbox -  Facebook style

Tags: asp.net, ajax, facebook, textbox, autocompleteextender

I have in my application a larger textbox and offer user the possibility to enter text on several rows like this:

first piece of text

second piece of text

and so on...

Each row is a distinct piece of data that has a significance. The thing is I would like to use ajax auto complete extender functionality after the user types a certain character on a row, such as @, and filter the records in the database according to the first letter the user typed after @, moment when the auto complete suggestion list would appear. For example, third piece of text @Action1, means that after the user typed A he would be prompted with a list of values to choose from.

There are several items of concern for me: first, it is possible to use autocomplete extender only for part of the text in the textbox, and second does it work like this for multiple rows (i.e. one time - in each line behaviour)? Regarding its position, I guess I have no other choice than at the bottom of the textbox it refers to, despite I would have liked it to appear below the @ symbol.

Thank you very much.

Update: I found something similar to what I am looking for here: [Twitter-style autocomplete in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157992/twitter-style-autocomplete-in-textarea), but the author only explained briefly his solution. Any help much appreciated, thx!

Answer (score 0):

> Each row is a distinct piece of data that has a significance.

Why are you using a textarea then, and not multiple `<input>` fields?

Sounds to me like your error in UI design lies right there already, so the rest of my answer is rather theoretical; I probably won’t go into more details as the sensible fix for your problem is the one above.

---

> first, it is possible to use autocomplete extender only for part of the text in the textbox,

Why shouldn’t it be? Cursor position in a textarea for example is readable (although it requires some working around cross-browser issues).

> and second does it work like this for multiple rows (i.e. one time - in each line behaviour)?

So long as the line breaks are “hard” ones (made by the user themselves, using enter/return), splitting the actual textarea content by `"\n"` to have each row as a single value is no problem.

> Regarding its position, I guess I have no other choice than at the bottom of the textbox it refers to, despite I would have liked it to appear below the @ symbol.

You could try to roughly measure the @’s position, by line and col number it is on, and match that to the character width and line height, when using a monospace font. For other fonts, some more “magic” might be required to measure the actual width of the previous text before the @ character.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/) package for this, which allows both free text and multiple autocomplete sources. Meteor's data model allows for fast multi-rule searching with custom rendered lists. If you're not using Meteor for your web app, (I believe) you unfortunately won't find anything this awesome for autocompletion.

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete

See the link for pictures of how it works. Fork, pull, and improve!