# Triggering Autocomplete with @

Tags: javascript

I am mostly a backend developer. And very new to javascript. So pardon my dumb question, but is there a way to trigger autocomplete when the user types '@' in a textfield. Like how it does in twitter.

Comment: take a look at http://flipnotes.net/notes/note/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got two answers for you:

1. I think this blog post has what you need: 
   [Triggered @mention Autocomplete like Facebook, Twitter and Google+](http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9391/)
   Github repo: https://github.com/Hawkers/triggeredAutocomplete
2. Also a similar question: [Twitter-style autocomplete in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157992/twitter-style-autocomplete-in-textarea)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at onkeyup if you are using straight javascript.  If you are using jQuery, try [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

From there, you can check to see if the user entered '@' and then make your auto-complete .

Comment: I wish I could mark both as correct. The other post was posted earlier thats why I marked it correct. Thank you so much for your answer though :)

Answer (score 2):

You could easily do it with http://complete-ly.appspot.com

just override the function onTextChange like this:

```
function onTextChange(text) {

   if (text.lastIndexOf('@') == text.length-1) { // ends with...

       // set the options, possibly change the text...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/) package for this purpose. Meteor's data model allows for fast multi-rule searching with custom rendered lists. If you're not using Meteor for your web app, (I believe) you unfortunately won't find anything this awesome for autocompletion.

Autocompleting users with `@`, where online users are shown in green:

[image]

In the same line, autocompleting something else using `!` with metadata and bootstrap icons:

[image]

Fork, pull, and improve:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete