# Free text input with autocomplete on special symbols

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, meteor, jquery-autocomplete, bootstrap-typeahead

I am building a chat widget that allows people to talk to each other in a web app. Most of the chat is therefore just text, but I'd like to allow people to say

[image]

which should appear in the chat as (for example)

[image]

Where typing the `@` symbol allows `Joe` to be autocompleted from a list of users and also rendered as some sort of HTML element that isn't just text.

A great example is the tags box when asking or editing a question on StackOverflow - you can type free text which autocompletes to one or more tags; I basically want the tags to activate with a particular symbol (`@` in this case) and still allow the free text otherwise. Another example is the comment reply field in StackOverflow where you can type `@fooUser this is my response to your comment` and `fooUser` becomes a link.

GitHub also does this; it provides different autocompletes for `#` (issue) and `@` (user), i.e.:

[image]

[image]

I'm aware of libraries such as [Twitter/Bootstrap typeahead](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me) and [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), but they seem to autocomplete an entire input and are not flexible enough for doing things like this. There are two main issues here:

- What's a good way to approach the hybrid rendering of both text and arbitrary DOM elements over an input field?
- Is there an autocomplete library that supports in-line autocompletion, not just on the entire input?

I'm also fine with not rendering DOM elements in the text input/text area, but I can't find any libraries that do this type of hybrid free-text/autocomplete at all.

As an aside, I'm doing this in Meteor and so the data source for the autocomplete will be a [Meteor collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection). While that shouldn't affect how the data is hooked up too much, a Meteor-aware answer would be even more helpful.

Related to **[Twitter-style autocomplete in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6157992/586086)** but that question is over 2 years old with no good answers and hopefully something better has come along by now.

Comment: One approach I can think of for your first question on rendering both text and dom elements over an input field may be to use html5 contenteditable attribute, which has pretty good browser support, even IE.

Comment: @kenttam Thanks, but I need a comprehensive way to do this, not a few tidbits for shooting in the dark here and there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was worth creating a Meteor package for this purpose:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete

The client-side data synchronization in Meteor makes this both really powerful and really flexible. Multiple matching rules and custom list rendering using templates are all supported:

Mentioning users, where online users are rendered in green:

[image]

Mentioning something else, along with some metadata shown

[image]

See the link for more details. Please fork, pull, and improve!

Comment: Too bad I can't use a Meteor package :(

Answer (score 2):

Nothing too promising turned up in an extensive canvassing of libraries, but I thought I'd write things down for reference.

I'm excluding all full-field autocompletion libraries such as Typeahead and jQuery-autocomplete since they're not really what I'm looking for.

- https://github.com/tactivos/jquery-sew (only supports one trigger)
- https://github.com/Hawkers/triggeredAutocomplete (also only one trigger)
- https://github.com/podio/jquery-mentions-input (one trigger, and unmaintained)
- http://imankulov.github.io/asuggest/ (not very complete)

At this point, I'm fairly certain there's no industrial-strength library unless GitHub decides to open-source their code :). Fingers crossed...