# Textarea with suggestions when user enters @

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to know how to implement a textarea where a user can tag people by typing @ and then write a person's name. You get inline suggestions for word matches.
I'm not even sure what the technical name would be for such a feature but it's a common in sites like Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You want an autocompleter of some sort.

Have a look at this [jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is using jQuery Tokeninput.

Hopefully you are looking for some [Twitter style autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157992/twitter-style-autocomplete-in-textarea)